# Split string at commas without putting it into an array

Tags: php, regex

I have a field in a MySQL db which holds a contact address:`1 The High Street, This Town, Some City,AA1 1AA`

I want to split it at the commas so it prints out as:

```
1 The High Street
This Town
Some City
AA1 1AA
```

I have tried explode(), implode(), split() and preg() but they dont work. I usually get `Array ( [0] => 1 The High Street [1] => This Town [2] => Some City [3] => AA1 1AA )` which I don't want.

I have looked at various answers on this site including those answers using Regex but I don't understand enough to make it work.

So, how do I get the string to split at the commas without putting it into an array?

Comment: After you have them in an array, you can manipulate them once more to transform them in the format you want them. You'll be glad to acquire that kind of programming  approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to replace the commas with a new line character? Javascript

```
yourString.split(",").join("\n")
```

Or in php - pick one depending on what you are trying to do.

```
str_replace(",","\n",$your_string);
str_replace(",","\r\n",$your_string);
str_replace(",","<br>",$your_string);
```

or you can use a regular expression to replace commas and spaces in php

```
preg_replace('/,\s*/i', '\n', $string);
preg_replace('/,\s*/i', '\r\n', $string);
preg_replace('/,\s*/i', '<br>', $string);
```

[Here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-create-a-new-line-in-php.php) is some data on line breaks in php depending on what you want to do.

Comment: What am I doing wrong? This just seems to remove the commas but still keeping everything on one line.

Comment: Where are you reading the output, did you read the link about line breaks in php? You may need \r\n.

Comment: Thanks @Diesel. I'd aready tried using the '\r\n' but the didn't make any difference. However, using the HTML version worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to put the output into a web page, you need to replace the ,'s with `<br>` tags...

```
$addressFormated = str_replace(",","<br>",$address);
```